# find r_hat value using numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am somewhat experienced with python but new to Numpy/Scipy. I am trying to find r_hat using the following constraints:

minimize: the sum of { w(a,b) * (r_hat(a,b) - (r(a,b)^2)) }

constraints: r_hat(a2,b2) > r_hat(a1,b1) -- in other words, r_hat should increase as a and b increase.

Another way to think of it is that I am trying to minimize the weighted sum of squares (the least of squares), but I am only searching for one coefficient, r_hat, as w and r change. For example:

w(r_hat - r)^2

In this equation, I am searching for what the value for r_hat is when the equation is minimized and I know the values of w and r.

I have the values of a,b, w(a,b), and r(a,b), though I don't have the formulas for w(a,b) and r(a,b). I don't think I need these formulas, though. I only want values for r_hat at the various points for a,b.

Any guidance (or even better, actual code!) to get me started would be greatly appreciated.

If this is unclear, please ask follow up questions!

Comment: What is the context of the problem, ie. what does `w(a,b), r, r_hat, a,b` represent? Is `r_hat` a unit distance vector? Are `a,b` constrained or can they take any real (or complex) value?